# Register a post_load hook after Schema defintion?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, marshalling, marshmallow

I'm trying to implement a Schema that [deserializes into an object](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/quickstart.html#deserializing-to-objects), where the object class is not known at Schema-definition time. I would have assumed that I can register a `post_load` function at runtime, but it [appears](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/381f6ae14c490f043cc0cf6156950de5f9894078/src/marshmallow/decorators.py#L169) that `post_load` works only for class methods.

It seems like I could make it work by either:

- Updating `Schema._hooks` manually or by
- Somehow creating a bound method at runtime and registering that.

Since both of these options are somewhat hack-ish, is there an official way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a metaclass.

Define a base schema with a post-load method that just needs the class.

```
class CustomSchema(Schema):

    @post_load
    def make_obj(self, data):
        return self.OBJ_CLS(**data)
```

If the class is known at import time (not your use case), this allows you to factorize the instantiation by just providing the class. Nice already.

```
class PetSchema(CustomSchema):

    OBJ_CLS = Pet
```

If the class is not known at import time, then it can be provided afterwards.

```
class PetSchema(CustomSchema):
    pass


PetSchema.OBJ_CLS = Pet
```

If you need some more processing before instantiating, then you can override `make_obj` in any class, as you show in your answer.

```
class PetSchema(CustomSchema):
    def make_obj(self, data):
        data = my_func(data)
        return Pet(**data)
```

---

More generally, this mechanism allows you to define hooks in a base schema. This is a good way to overcome a current limitation in marshmallow: the fact that multiple `post_load` methods can be executed in any order. Define a single `post_load` method in a base class with a hook for each processing step. (This contrived example doesn't really illustrate the point.)

```
class CustomSchema(Schema):

    @post_load
    def post_load_steps(self, data):
        data = self.post_load_step_1(data)
        data = self.post_load_step_2(data)
        data = self.post_load_step_3(data)
        return data

    def post_load_step_1(self, data):
        return data

    def post_load_step_2(self, data):
        return data

    def post_load_step_3(self, data):
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone else need this, I've solved it with a custom metaclass that pre-registers a post_load function whose actual implementation can be supplied at runtime:

```python
from types import MethodType

from marshmallow import Schema, post_load
from marshmallow.schema import SchemaMeta

class MyCustomSchemaMeta(SchemaMeta):

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def make_obj(*args, **kwargs):
            raise NotImplementedError

        # This post_load call registers the method with the Schema._hooks dict
        cls.make_obj = post_load(make_obj)

class MyCustomSchema(Schema, metaclass=MyCustomSchemaMeta):
    """This is the base class that my schemas inherit."""

# The actual implementation of make_obj (and hence the class to deserialize to)
# can now be provided at runtime. The post_load call does not affect the schema
# anymore, but sets some parameters on the method.
MyCustomSchema.make_obj = MethodType(
    post_load(lambda self, data: MyClass(**data)), MyCustomSchema
)
```